# Informatica Scenario

Tags: database, informatica

I have data in source as shown below:

```
source
id    value
--------------
1      a
1      b
1      c
2      l
3      d
3      e
```

I want data in target as shown below:

```
target
id    value
--------------
1     a,b,c
2     l
3     d,e
```

I can do that data in id=1 should go to one target, id=2 to second target and id=3 in third target as shown below:

```
Target1
id    value
--------------
1     a
1     b
1     c

Target2
id    value
--------------
2     l

Target3
id    value
--------------
3     d
3     e
```

but how we can make values of ID=1 in one column in comma separated form as required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregator or expression transform for this. Please see the [example](https://community.informatica.com/mpresources/docs/Userguide_1628.pdf) provided by INFA community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use first expression transformation and then aggregater transformation.
In expression try to concatenate the column 'Value' by using logic explained in below link
'https://community.informatica.com/message/59800'

then aggregate on Id column.